# Show LongListSelector in JumpList mode

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to show my LongListSelector in JumpList mode so the user can have a quick access to the categories I created. Is that possible? I didn't found anything relevant on MSDN's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. Have a look at this example, it helped me learn how to do it.

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth